# Parameters in startsWith(String word, char c)

Tags: java, startswith

I am struggling with understanding a practice task that I have received in preparation for a test I have in a few days. This is the code that I have so far:

```
/**
 * Check if the first letter in this word matches the given letter c
 * @param word a word
 * @param c - a character a-z upper or lower case
 * @return true if first letter in word matches c
 */
@Override
public boolean startsWith(String word, char c) {
}
```

I am supposed to write code that will pass the test requirements that I have in a separate file. All of the test code has already been given to me, and my only task is to write code that returns true if the first letter in String word matches char c. It does not matter if the letter is in uppercase or if it is in lowercase as the file with the test code contains code that handles this problem.
To summarize:
I guess what I am asking for is help in understanding what exactly I'm supposed to do? I have tried writing something along the lines of this, but I do not think this is correct and I think I am completely ignoring and neglecting a huge part of the task:

```
@Override
public boolean startsWith(String word, char c) {
    if (word.startsWith(word, c)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess what I'm struggling with is figuring out what to put instead of word and c in the parenthesis in the if-statement.

Comment: Why do you think what you have here is not correct?  Have you tried to compile it?

Comment: If the only thing you have to do is compare the first character in ```word```, and ```return true``` if that is equal to ```c```, you can jus simply: ```return word.charAt(0) == c;```

Comment: You can add a check in the beginning to test if word is not null, otherwise you may get a nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you've misunderstood the arguments to the [`startsWith()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String,%20int)) method.  The first argument is the prefix.  That should be your character, `c`.  The second argument is the offset to start looking for that prefix at.  In this case, you want that to be 0.  What you really want is `word.startsWith(Character.toString(c), 0)`.  The reason your original code didn't throw a compile-time exception is because the character `c` was just being treated like a number, and it was being upcasted to an int in order to match the method header of the `startsWith()` method.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much to your advantage to learn where to find the JavaDocs for the version of the Java Standard Library you are using.  Those for Java 10 are here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html, and those for several other versions are nearby.  Among the things you can do with those is look up classes of interest, such as [`java.lang.String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), to determine what methods they provide and to learn details of those methods' arguments and behavior.

In particular, you might consider checking `String`'s several `startsWith()` methods, in which case you would find that they determine whether the `String` object *on which they are invoked* starts with a specific string or a string matching a specific pattern.  That's not how you are trying to use the one that matches your invocation's arguments.

Another answer describes you you might apply `String.startsWith()` to your problem, but that's not your only option.  Perusing the available methods would turn up several ways to get individual `char`s from the `String`, such as the `charAt()` method.  If indeed you don't need to worry about case (which sounds surprising to me) then, personally, I would be inclined to extract the first character (at index 0) and compare that to the character of interest.  That is, I would start here:

```
char firstChar = word.charAt(0);
```

The rest is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

string startsWith method documentation from [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> startsWith(String prefix, int offset)

> Tests if the substring of this
> string beginning at the specified index starts with the specified
> prefix.

But you need to test whether the first character starts with character c. So you can use the overloaded version of startsWith(String word) (from String). here is my 2 options:

option 1:

```
@Override
public boolean startsWith(String word, char c) {
    return word.charAt(0) == c; 
}
```

option 2:

```
@Override
public boolean startsWith(String word, char c) {
    return word.startsWith(String.valueOf(c); 
}
```

Note that you can improve this method by checking the "word" argument nullity as mentioned in answers. for example:

```
@Override
public boolean startsWith(String word, char c) {
    return word != null && word.startsWith(String.valueOf(c); 
}
```